# How I can unit-test APIs?

Tags: 7, testing

How I can unit-test APIs? Is there any method for asserting API response in drupal 7?

Answer (score -1):

You can find an example in the [Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module. Here are two excellent guides:

- [Simpletest Testing tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/testing/simpletest-testing-tutorial-drupal-7)
- [Unit Testing with SimpleTest](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/testing/unit-testing-with-simpletest)

Comment: How i can access my api from Simpletest?